# Log of user actions in the DB - using SimpleMembership, sql server log?

Tags: sql-server-2008, simplemembership

I have an asp.net application that uses SimpleMembership (WebSecurity etc.) & Sql Server 2008 R2.
The authentication is done in the application.
What is the simplest way to keep track of the user actions in the DB - something like this:

User XXXX updated table tb_XXXXX with values XXXXx,XXXX,XXXX on date XXX/XXXX/XXX.

I'm thinking of using the built in SQL server log file, but how can I add the information from SimpleMembership to it? (i.e. which user updated the table)

Thank you

Gilad

Answer (score 0):

Its not specific for your needs but I use log4net which is nice library.

You can read about it here: [Code Project - log4net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8245/A-Brief-Introduction-to-the-log-net-logging-librar)